# My Xamarin Form EditText event FocusChange will not fire

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When an EditText receives Focus I want to Select all Entered text in this field.
In my code behind file I have:

```
    private EditText _scanItem;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "inventory" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.inventory);

         _scanItem = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);

        _scanItem.FocusChange += _scanItem_FocusChange;
     }

             private void _scanItem_FocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_scanItem.HasFocus == true)
            _scanItem.SelectAll();
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead use _scanItem.SetSelectAllOnFocus(true);

Done!